# Remove elements from javascript array by position

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a javascript array

```
var countries = ["India","USA","China","Canada","China"];
```

I want to remove "China" only from 2nd position, and return

`var countries = ["India","USA","Canada","China"];`

Something similar to java `linkedlist.remove(index)`

I have read following question but I don't know how to use it if there are duplicate elements in array.
[How do I remove a particular element from an array in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5767325/remove-specific-element-from-an-array)

Comment: are you looking for array.splice?

Comment: @InvernoMuto I am not sure whether I can use  array.splice in this situation.

Comment: You are Right, before to call splice you have to locate your "China" recurrence, you can use IndexOf otherwise LastIndexOf otherwise you havee to craft a custom IndexFilter

Comment: you can definitely use str.indexOf(searchValue[, fromIndex]) where fromIndex is the starting recurrence of your value

Comment: So many answers, not of which does what asked for. See my answer, it does exactly what you asked for

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try splice():

```
countries.splice(2,1);
```

Here, first argument is the position and second is the number of elements to remove.

To get the index use indexOf(), -1 if not found:

```
countries.indexOf("China");
```

So you have:

```
var i = countries.indexOf("China");
if(-1 !== i) {
    countries.splice(i, 1);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a mix of [`array.indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) and [`array.splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice).

```
var countries = ["India","USA","China","Canada","China"];
var first_china = countries.indexOf("China");

if(first_china > -1){
    countries.splice(first_china , 1);
}
```

The question you linked also has the same answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/5767357).  `indexOf` will return you the index of the *first* match it finds.  So if there are duplicates, it will still only remove the first one.

Comment: this will remove first element not the last

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [JavaScript Array `splice()`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_splice.asp) Method.

```js
var countries = ["India", "USA", "China", "Canada", "China"];
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = countries;

function myFunction() {
  countries.splice(2, 1);
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = countries;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="myFunction()">SPLICE!</button>
<p id="demo"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var c = ["India","USA","China","Canada","China"];
// provide the index you want to remove here (2)
var c2 = c.filter(function(item, idx) {if(idx != 2) return item;});

console.log(c2);
```

**DEMO**: http://jsfiddle.net/kf8epwnh/